# Single word for "humorous in an intellectual way"

Tags: single-word-requests

How to describe something (in this case, a description) that is humorous in an intellectual way?

Comment: Shades of "witty": "arch," "ironic," "sardonic"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **witty**
>   *adjective* ( wittier , wittiest )
>   showing or characterized by quick and inventive verbal humor: *a witty remark* | *Marlowe was charming and witty.*
>
> <sub>NOAD</sub>

I think this is about as close as you can come. It has its origins in *wit*, obviously, which means "mental sharpness and inventiveness; keen intelligence."

Answer (score 3):

According to wiktionary, adjective *[dry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dry)* has a sense

> (of a person or joke) Subtly humorous, yet without mirth.

That is, wiktionary suggests that dry humor does not lead to laughter, merriment, jollity; but dry humor still is considered essentially funny and unstrained.  *[Bloodless](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bloodless)* humor, on the other hand, is humor that is "lacking emotion, passion or vivacity".  You might also refer to *[wry](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/wry)* humor, which includes senses

> • Humorously sarcastic or mocking; "dry humor"; "an ironic remark often conveys an intended meaning obliquely"; "an ironic novel"; "an ironical smile"; "with a wry Scottish wit"
>   • Disdainfully or ironically humorous; scornful and mocking; "his rebellion is the bitter, sardonic laughter of all great satirists"

Answer (score 3):

**droll** means *funny* or *amusing*. It doesn't necessarily mean *intellectual*, but as many people seem not to know exactly what it *does* mean, I think it can carry that connotation (at least in AmE).

Answer (score 1):

**Clever** is another alternative that comes to mind.

Comment: Using *clever* in the sense of 'intellectual' hurts.  

People do use it with a positive connotation.

Answer (score 1):

*Facetious*: cleverly amusing in tone.

Comment: Good answer! A sentence using the word might be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Amuse (v) to provide interesting and enjoyable occupation for (someone). 
          to cause to laugh or smile by giving pleasure.

And, as the Queen of England might say: "We are not amused"