# Word for "Intellectual Prankster"

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to express concisely an impish attitude some clever scientists have. I want these properties:

- Explicitly playful (or maybe mischievous)
- Intellectual, but in action: Not always verbal, as in [*witty*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/64414/39720)
- Ethically neutral: No connotations of underhandedness, as in [*crafty*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crafty)

In particular, I read a biography about a scientist who would crack his coworkers' safes. He did not use his knowledge malevolently, but he also shouldn't have been doing it. When a coworker suspected an intruder stole files, the scientist let him panic for a while before confessing.

Is there a single word for "intellectually impish"?

Comment: Sounds like Feynman. This sort of prank is common at tech schools; see also the [Caltech-MIT rivalry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caltech%E2%80%93MIT_rivalry). These pranks are called “hacks” at MIT, but I don't think there's a word for it in general English. Most folks seem to get the meaning well enough from _prank_ in context.

Comment: @BraddSzoyne: It was Feynman! Would the one committing a hack be a hacker? I'm hesitant to use *prank* or *prankster*, because I would also like to describe magicians with this word. A magician plays on one's beliefs that something can't be done and then by illusion or skill convinces one that it can.

Comment: Yes, that subculture would call such a prankster a _hacker,_ but the word has too many other connotations to be understood that way by the general population.

Comment: By the way, if you're interested in this sort of thing, you may want to check out [The Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/jargon/), which is all about hacker language and culture (in the sense used here).

Comment: I think "cunning" has impish undertones and certainly is more action than verbal.

Comment: How about Machiavellian?  That relates to scheming, trickery, etc.

Comment: @Ste *Cunning* is very close; it has everything I want in describing the particular examples of Feynman and magicians. But I think more than mischievous/trouble-making, I'm looking for *playful*. (I'll update my question accordingly.) The "intellectual maverick" I'm describing will do unusual, funny things out of scientific curiosity.

Comment: Mischievous, crafty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Cunning* and *sly* are both very good; but since you ask specifically for *impish*, may I suggest a word derived from the very archetype of the mischievous imp:

> that shrewd and knavish sprite
> Call'd Robin Goodfellow: are not you he
> That frights the maidens of the villagery;
> Skim milk, and sometimes labour in the quern
> And bootless make the breathless housewife churn;
> And sometime make the drink to bear no barm;
> Mislead night-wanderers, laughing at their harm?
> Those that Hobgoblin call you and sweet Puck,
> You do their work, and they shall have good luck:
> Are not you he?

***Puckish***, too, is a word often applied to Feynman:

> ... this play [*QED*]  is a tour-de-force that captures his unique and puckish genius. —Publisher's blurb
>
> Feynman was widely known for his insatiable curiosity and puckish sense of humor.  —[*Colored Reflections*](http://www.coloredreflections.com/decades/Decade.cfm?Dec=4&Typ=2&Sty=1&SID=147) (blog)
>
> During this talk Feynman drilled—with impressive prescience and the puckish humor he was well-known for—right to the heart of the question he had raised.  —[*I'm Working on That*](http://metamerist.blogspot.com/2006/03/richard-feynman.html), Wiliam Shatner
>
> He was puckish—cracking safes, demonstrating the cause of the Challenger disaster on national television with a C-clamp and kindergarten words, naming one of his books in mockery of Princeton's high tea. —[*Metamerist*](http://metamerist.blogspot.com/2006/03/richard-feynman.html) (blog)

Comment: I like *puckish*! *Impish* feels insulting (like *hooligan*) when used on an intellectual figure, but I think the literary background of *puckish* detracts from that some. Those descriptions are exactly what I want to convey. The word seems to fit pretty well with another figure I want to describe: Raymond Smullyan, of Knight-and-Knave Paradox fame. I don't like the connection with *knavish* in the quote above, but after looking through definitions from several sources it doesn't seem common. Will accept answer tomorrow, if no words better capturing ethical-neutrality or intelligence arise!

Answer (score 2):

I think *sly* fits the bill. The third [dictionary.com definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sly) defines it as

> playfully artful, mischievous, or roguish

And, in fact, since (according to the comments on your question) you're referring to Richard Feynman, it might be helpful to mention that a number of examples can be found in the wild of people using this exact term to describe Feynman (this is clearly not a scientific survey by any means, but just a collection of examples).

For example, in the [introduction to QED](http://www.kitp.ucsb.edu/members/PM/zee/feynman.html) A. Zee writes

> I chuckled a few times as Feynman got in some sly digs at other
>   physicists.

In a [forbes.com article](http://www.forbes.com/forbes/2002/0318/039_print.html) the author refers in passing to

> a bit of Richard Feynman sly magic

In a [review](http://www.comicsbulletin.com/reviews/2400/feynman/) of a comic featuring Feynman, the reviewer writes

> The cover alone almost feels more real than photographs of the man,
>   having boiled down his essence into this inquisitive, sly smirk, the
>   outward representation of the scientific curiosity that drove him
>   every day of his life.

In a [scientific paper](http://www.oberlin.edu/physics/dstyer/StrangeQM/Moment.pdf) building upon some of Feynman's work, the author writes

> This result came out eight years after Feynman's death, but I can
>   imagine him looking at the equation with a sly smile.

And that's just some of them. A google search reveals a number of other examples.

Comment: *Sly* is a good word, particularly for the way he pulled the prank with the safes. But [*sly*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sly) also has a secretive connotation that I'm not always looking for. +1 for the well-researched answer, though.